# Difference between BOW(Bag Of Words) and TextBlob

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, textblob

I am newbie in that area. Recently doing a sentiment analysis on twitter data. And came across with two approaches: 
1)TextBlob - python library for processing textual data
2) BOW (Bag Of Words)

What is the difference between them? Is the two difference approach or have any similarity?

Answer (score 1):

Bag of words and TextBlob are used for Text processing in NLP tasks. Bag of words is a model/concept used in NLP whereas TextBlob is a python library used for processing textual data.

A bag-of-words model, or BoW for short, is a way of extracting features from the text for use in modeling, such as with machine learning algorithms.

The approach is very simple and flexible and can be used in a myriad of ways for extracting features from documents.

A bag-of-words is a representation of text that describes the occurrence of words within a document. It involves two things:

A vocabulary of known words.
A measure of the presence of known words.
It is called a “bag” of words because any information about the order or structure of words in the document is discarded. The model is only concerned with whether known words occur in the document, not wherein the document.
Read more:- https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-bag-words-model/

TextBlob is a Python library for processing textual data. It provides a simple API for diving into common natural language processing (NLP) tasks such as part-of-speech tagging, noun phrase extraction, sentiment analysis, classification, translation, and more.
Read more:- https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/

Tutorial:- https://stackabuse.com/python-for-nlp-introduction-to-the-textblob-library/